# cake mix or mixture? Are they synonyms?

Tags: vocabulary

Would you refer to the packaged powdered ingredients as cake mix or cake mixture?

I suspect the difference, which I am by no means certain of, is that "cake mixture" refers to cake mix with water added, while "cake mix" refers to the powered form before water is added. Can someone tell me if this is the case?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: That is my understanding as well, but I don't have a reference for you.

Comment: *Cake mix* has become [much more common in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cake+mix%2Cthe+cake+mixture&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cake%20mix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cake%20mixture%3B%2Cc0) in the past couple of decades. *Cake mixture* remains [the dominant form in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cake+mix%2Cthe+cake+mixture&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cake%20mix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cake%20mixture%3B%2Cc0). But they mean the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Knowing you is just like going to college. All the time I've spent on your fabled isle, and I only now learnt about _cake mixture._ So, if I were to pop in at the grocer's and ask for a box of "cake mix", he'd give me the hairy eyeball?

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I've often said I think BrE is less resistant to change than AmE. Partly because it's nearly always *us* who have to fall into line when US/UK usage differences affect global companies (Betty Crocker wouldn't want to bother with special *Chocolate Cake **Mixture*** packaging for the UK market, and it's not like many Brits would even *notice*, let alone care).

Comment: ...you might find [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+mix%2Cto+mix&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20mix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20mix%3B%2Cc0) interesting. It shows how recently and rapidly the *noun* usage ***a mix*** (as opposed to *verb* usage ***to mix***) has gained traction. And if you toggle between US/UK corpuses, I think you'll agree that shift has been faster and more marked in BrE. So no - no hairy eyeball in the UK if you ask the shopkeeper for a packet of cake mix!